# What is dbus_enable?

Tags: rhel, xfce, lightdm, alma-linux

I am hoping someone can explain what `dbus_enable` is and what benefits it would bring should I include it.

Additionally I am not sure where this would be placed however I feel it may be added to the `~/.bash_profile` file, like so:

```
# User specific environment and startup programs
dbus_enable=YES
```

The reason I ask this is because I stumbled across some old posts, which I've listed below:

[dbus_enable and hald_enable](https://groups.google.com/g/muc.lists.freebsd.questions/c/WtVuwavuLYo)

[KDE and dbus_enable](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/kde-and-dbus_enable.81144/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbus_enable` is a FreeBSD configuration option which controls whether [`dbus-daemon`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?dbus-daemon(1)) is started. This provides an interprocess communications bus, D-Bus, used by some desktop environments (including GNOME and KDE) and various other tools commonly used on Linux systems (not so much FreeBSD). The setting is stored in `/etc/rc.conf`.

Your tags suggest you’re using RHEL or Alma Linux; `dbus_enable` is irrelevant there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This is clear to me and it's good to know that it doesn't need to be included in my AlmaLinux environment.